# How to build Python3 WITHOUT support for tk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, build

Basically I want to build a minimal version of Python 3 (this will be running on a headless server, so no GUI, no mouse, no keyboard). The dependency on tk for most Python packages pulls in X and bunch of other UI things I dont want.

There's nothing in `./configure --help` that tells me how to switch off building with tk. And nothing in the `README` file included with the source tarball either. Its been surprisingly hard to find info about this, so what kind of spell is needed ?

Comment: I don't file a answer because I cannot be specific. But the place where you should look is `Modules/Setup.dist`. Anyway take care that the documentation of the standard library is the most of footprint but remove it is little bit tricky. If I'll remember, Monday I can take a look of how I did it for python 2.4 on blackfin and try to file a answer. Feel free to send me a message to remember it.

Comment: The unix/linux buildbots are generally headless.  Assuming that they are build without tk, you *might* find something in Tool/buildbot that helps.

Comment: Same problem, especially with macOS.

Comment: I want that option too ... there is not --without-tcl-tk flag of configure in cpython but it would be great if there was. I do not want all that tkinter and idle in my pthon - it is just a source of problems. I had a look at it and I am never going to use idle or tcl-tk , for one type of situation - I do not want any GUI, and when I want a GUI (another situation and another build) I prefer to use other frameworks (e.g. Qt). The "batteries included" approach of python release is a pain here, those batteries for GUI would be better in an external module not standard library

Answer (score 1):

If the server you are trying to build Python on does not have tcl/tk installed, then Python will skip that portion during its build process.

Comment: It would be really good to build "lean" version of python without tk, even in a situation when my development environment has that particular gui framework installed (eg a Xcode pushed bad one on a MacOS). I just want to turn it off in the build, not to modify the environment... and easily

Comment: Also what about when cross-compiling to another target, like building Python for embedded systems...

Answer (score 1):

It's not so complicated, just change the build file `Modules/Setup` as such:

### `Modules/Setup`

```diff
diff --git a/Modules/Setup b/Modules/Setup
index 8fe7951278..dabdcc6212 100644
--- a/Modules/Setup
+++ b/Modules/Setup
@@ -300,3 +300,7 @@ PYTHONPATH=$(COREPYTHONPATH)
 #
 # _sqlite3 _tkinter _curses pyexpat
 # _codecs_jp _codecs_kr _codecs_tw unicodedata
+#
+*disabled*
+
+_tkinter
```